# Getting the last token String

Tags: java

I have a application that needs to read a `String` buffer that is semi-colon '`;`' delimited.

```
String buff = foo.getBuff(); // returns the buffer
```

However, the buffer can get pretty large and I just need to get the last String *token* and then flush the temporary variable `String buff` so my app won't accumulate much memory.

**Update:**

I tried this code:

```
String lastToken = buff.substring(buff.lastIndexOf(";") + 1);
```

However, I am not getting result with this code above, compared to this:

```
List<String> slist = Arrays.asList(buff.split(";"));
String lastToken = slist.get(slist.size() - 1);
```

However using List is very slow. My web app is almost not responding when processing this.

Comment: Provide an example on which my solution is not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will help you:

```
String lastToken = buff.substring(buff.lastIndexOf(";") + 1);
```

Comment: I'm not getting result with this code, compared to: List<String> slist = Arrays.asList(buff.split(";"));
       String lastToken = slist.get(slist.size() - 1);

Comment: Try this to see it working. Then, replace s with your string.     String s = "fsdfsdfgdfdgdfg;dgdgdfgd;gdfgdf";
String lastToken = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(";") + 1);

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Java, but by googling 2 functions, I think something like this should work:

```
String buff = foo.getBuff(); // returns the buffer
String lastToken = buff.substring(buff.lastIndexOf(";")+1);
```

Comment: I'm not getting result with this code, compared to: List<String> slist = Arrays.asList(buff.split(";"));
       String lastToken = slist.get(slist.size() - 1);

Comment: However my solution is quite slow

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
String lastToken = foo.getBuff().substring(foo.getBuff().lastIndexOf(';')+1);
```

Edit: Dan gave the answer better and faster than me.